# Zend_Auth no giving all info

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, zend-auth

I am having this issue with Zend and Doctrine and I am hoping someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong:-

My login controller is as follow:

```
....    
if ($result->isValid()) {

   $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('tcc.auth');

      $identity = $adapter->getResultArray('password');

      $auth->getStorage()->write($identity); 
.....
```

In my index controller dispatch I call

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('tcc.auth');
```

what is not working as I hoped is that if I do this:

```
print_r (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity());
```

I get the all Array correctly, bit if I want to get ie userid only and do this:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->userid;
```

I get nothing. It is just empty!

I am puzzled about what I am doing wrong. Can someone please please help?

Comment: and what does `$identity` store ?

Comment: The all user information -> the array

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but if it's returning an array, shouldn't it be retrieved using array indices?

    $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    $userId = $identity['userid'];

Comment: dinopmi! You have been my savior other times..and this time too. Thank god you are here!. It does work that way...I really appreciate your reply. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be able to help... I'm converting my comment into an answer for the posterity ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but if it's an array, wouldn't this be the proper way to retrieve it?

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
$userId = $identity['userid'];
```

Hope that helps,